# Open multiple terminals through pssh

Tags: remote

```
pssh -h host.txt -X cscuser /bin/bash<<< 'gnome-terminal;cat /etc/resolv.conf'
```

I tried to use this to open multiple terminal on my clients computers but I get errors like

```
[1] 14:34:31 [FAILURE] 10.20.10.214 Exited with error code 255
[2] 14:34:31 [FAILURE] 10.20.10.201 Exited with error code 255
```

I need to open terminals on my client's computer OR run `top` commands to get CPU usage in parallel. How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this using the following command.

```
pssh -h <hostfile> -l <username> "-O StrictHostKeyChecking=no" -A -i "top -b -n1"
```

Change `<hostfile>` to the file name of you host file, and change `<username>` to the remote username.

You can remove the `"-O StrictHostKeyChecking=no"` option if this is not the first time you are connecting to the machine using pssh or ssh.

You have to run the `top` command in batch mode as you are running it via remote. Thats why we used `-b` flag with `top`

`-n` means number of iterations. So if we set it to 1 (`-n1`), then it will give one instance of top output. You can change the value to get more instances.

`-i` used to get the standers output and standers error as each host completes

`-A` used to get the prompt for a password and pass it to ssh. If you are using ssh keys, then you can exclude this flag.

Comment: thank you it's work fine! and i need that CPU usage only, i try to get that values but i could not ! how to get that only the CPU usage value